# Calling a webservice from C# I get "The requested address is not valid in its context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, sockets

Making a basic webservice call from a Windows Service running on Windows 2008 R2 connecting to IIS on the same machine I am getting the error that

> AddressNotAvailable  The requested address is not valid in it's
>   context 10.1.10.100

The machine IP is 10.1.10.100 has as been confirmed to be the only IP on the NIC card using ipconfig to verify that.
Below is the .NET Trace of when the web service request happens from the windows data service.  I've confirmed and I can browse to the web service url without any issue I also tested using telnet and it has no problems but I cannot figure out why the web service call fails.

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21688] WebRequest::Create(http://10.1.10.100/interstore/webservices/DeviceServerWebService.asmx)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21688] HttpWebRequest#13092880::HttpWebRequest(http://10.1.10.100/interstore/webservices/DeviceServerWebService.asmx#754204183)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21688] Exiting HttpWebRequest#13092880::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21688] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> HttpWebRequest#13092880
System.Net Information: 0 : [21688] Associating HttpWebRequest#13092880 with ServicePoint#49942457
System.Net Information: 0 : [21688] Associating HttpWebRequest#13092880 with ServicePoint#49942457
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21688] HttpWebRequest#13092880::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [21688] Associating Connection#9678369 with HttpWebRequest#13092880
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Socket#27673121::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Exiting Socket#27673121::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Socket#23463452::Socket(AddressFamily#23)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Exiting Socket#23463452::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] DNS::GetHostAddresses(dev900srv19)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] DNS::GetHostByName(dev900srv19)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Exiting DNS::GetHostByName()    -> IPHostEntry#34617479
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Exiting DNS::GetHostAddresses()     -> IPAddress[]#65308991
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Socket#27673121::InternalBind(10.1.10.100:0#1678377226)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Exiting Socket#27673121::InternalBind() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Socket#27673121::Connect(10.1.10.100:80#1678377306)
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [21688] Socket#27673121::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - AddressNotAvailable
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [21688] Exception in Socket#27673121::Connect - The requested address is not valid in its context 10.1.10.100:80.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Socket#27673121::Dispose()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21688] Socket#23463452::Dispose()
System.Net Error: 0 : [21688] Exception in HttpWebRequest#13092880:: - Unable to connect to the remote server.
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
System.Net Error: 0 : [21688] Exception in HttpWebRequest#13092880::EndGetRequestStream - Unable to connect to the remote server.
at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
```

Code:

```
    private void DoHeartbeat()
    {
        try
        {
            // Do Heartbeat
            var deviceServerWebService = new ADC.DataService.DeviceServerWebService.DeviceServerWebService();
            deviceServerWebService.HeartbeatCompleted += DeviceServerWebServiceHeartbeatCompleted;

            var url = GetHeartbeatUrl();
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                deviceServerWebService.Url = url;
            }

            string upTime = GetUpTime();
            long freeDriveSpace = GetDriveSpace();
            long freeMemory = GetFreeMemory();

            //Add a check , if there is a production total retrieval interval, read from the header in the ST event pnd file, that is greater than the current HeartBeatInterval update device status. 
            var recurrenceInterval = GetRecurrenceInterval();
            if (!recurrenceInterval.HasValue || (recurrenceInterval.HasValue && recurrenceInterval.Value > _Config.HeartbeatTimer.GetValueOrDefault(60) && _Config.DotNetScaleComms == true))
            {
                if (_BatchMgr != null)
                {
                    _BatchMgr.GetDeviceStatus();
                }
            }

            var computerName = GetComputerName();
            var macAddress = GetMacAddress();
            var deviceServerType = IsStore() ? DeviceServerWebService.DeviceServerTypeEnum.ISP : DeviceServerWebService.DeviceServerTypeEnum.Central;

            deviceServerWebService.HeartbeatAsync(computerName, macAddress, deviceServerType, _Config.ServerPort, License.Version.MajorVersionNumber, License.Version.MinorVersionNumber, License.Version.PatchVersionNumber, License.Version.BuildVersionNumber, freeDriveSpace, freeMemory, upTime, "", "", false, 0, 2, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = String.Format("[DataService.DoHeartbeat] {0}: {1}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
            LogMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code for your service call and give more context. Also, why not use "localhost" if its same machine instead of IP address?

Comment: Have you checked the port to make sure something else isn't running on there? Maybe try switching to a different port other than :80.

Comment: Do you use DHCP? If I remember correctly, you can't bind a socket to a static IP if you are using DHCP, even if that's the assigned IP (you could bind the service to `0.0.0.0` if that's the case)

Comment: I added the DoHeartbeat function that contains the creation of the webservice object sets the URL from a config file (http://10.1.10.100/interstore/webservices/DeviceServerWebService.asmx) grabs some data and then makes the call.  This all works locally when I use my IP address which is DHCP.  Where this is having an error the IP is a static IP address but we have other locations with static and DHCP address that all work fine.

Comment: Thank you to John Saunders for editing my post to make it more readable I fiddled with it for a while and just couldn't get it to do what you did.  Thanks

Comment: I've now tested with localhost and 127.0.0.1 in the URL and both return the same errors about the requested address is not valid in this context.  Could this be some kind of crazy permissions issue?